# Android programatically set margin to ImageButton in TableRow

Tags: android, margin, imagebutton, tablerow

I have defined a TableLayout in my Java code. For each row, I'm displaying three ImageButtons. When one of those buttons is pressed, the background color changes. To display it nicely, I have set a padding of 10px.

The problem I'm having now is that if you press two buttons that are next to each other, you don't exactly see a break between the buttons. So I'm wondering, is there a possibility to set a margin on the ImageButtons or an other solution whatshowever?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
int leftMargin = 10;
((MarginLayoutParams) imageButton.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = leftMargin;
```

**EDIT:**
If you don't use `ImageButton` defined in xml, you have to set `LayoutParams` like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = 10;
b.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Here I assume you use `LinearLayout` in your list item.

Comment: I tried but my app crashed. This is the code I used: http://pastebin.com/ibB3840J

Comment: I thought you have imagebutton defined in xml, but you create it in code, so you need to set `LayoutParams to it instead of getting them. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but I'm using a TableLayout. So I've replaced the LinearLayout for a TableLayout, but the ImageButtons are not showing in the emulator. Is this solution bound to LinearLayout only?

Comment: My solution is for `ListView`, but try to replace `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` with `TableLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: Or maybe with `TableRow.LayoutParams`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use to use the `LayoutParams` for the container the control is in. In your case the buttons are in a `TableRow` so use `TableRow.LayoutParams` if you use any other type of params, the control will not show at all.